# Power BI Bar Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table of customers that has these data

```
CustomerID  DemandHour  PurchaseHour
   1001          15         19
   1002          03         07
   1003          19         07
   1004          23         19
   1005          15         19
   1006          23         16
   1007          15         10
```

I want to find the count of customers of each hour

I want to graph them to look like this

[image]

I tried to count(DemandHour), and Count(PurchaseHour)

but ended with graph were both giving the same results

count(DemandHour)= Count(PurchaseHour)

How Can I do that ???

Appreciate your help.

Comment: what is on the x-axis?

Comment: The hour of the day 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 22, 23

Comment: but where is this hour coming from in your data?

Comment: I can create a table that only has 0,1,2,3,..,22, 23

Comment: and then how will you connect this table to your customer data table? On what fields?

Comment: I tried that, it only link one field to the table I linked DemandHour to the new table Hour field but could not link PurchaseHour to the same table.. this was an issue

Comment: Ok, I'll help you in a few minutes.

Comment: @RADO Thx Mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to build a data model with proper relations:

[image]

Here, I added a table "Time" containing day hours (1-24), and connected it to your main table (I call it "Data") with 2 connections:

- Main connection: between Time[Hour] and Data[DemandHour];
- Secondary: between Time[Hour] and Data[PurchaseHour]

Only main connection is active; the secondary connection is inactive, as indicated by the dotted line. However, you can employ it through DAX.

Next, create 2 measures:

```
Demand Customer Count = COUNT(Data[CustomerID])
```

and:

```
Purchase Customer Count =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Data[CustomerID] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Data[PurchaseHour], 'Time'[Hour] )
)
```

The first measure is simple; the second measure is the same, except we tell Power BI to use the inactive connection instead of the main one.

Result (based on your data sample):

[image]